# How do you search a chess database for exchange sacrifices?

Tags: software, sacrifice, cql

I am looking for a way within any of the common chess packages to search for a specific maneuver, such as a rook capturing a protected. bishop. I've heard of [CQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20140130143815/http://www.rbnn.com/cql), but have never used it. I am curious if it supports something like this.

Answer (score 8):

Chess Query Language does do this very well. The following short .cql file works like a charm to find all games in input.pgn in which one side is up an exchange (while allowing a difference in the number of pawns for each side) for 4 straight moves (picked so as to rule out, say, situations in which an equal sequence of trades happens to begin with a rook taking a minor piece, or other such temporary pseudo-sacrifices).

```
(match
    :pgn input.pgn
    :output output.pgn
    (position
    :sequence(
        (position :powerdifference [Rr] -5 -5 :powerdifference [Qq] 0 0 :powerdifference [BbNn] 3 3)
        (position :powerdifference [Rr] -5 -5 :powerdifference [Qq] 0 0 :powerdifference [BbNn] 3 3)
        (position :powerdifference [Rr] -5 -5 :powerdifference [Qq] 0 0 :powerdifference [BbNn] 3 3)
        (position :powerdifference [Rr] -5 -5 :powerdifference [Qq] 0 0 :powerdifference [BbNn] 3 3)
    )
    :flipcolor
    )
)
```

Standard point values for pieces are used, so the `:powerdifference [Rr] -5 -5` condition means that Black has one more rook than White, while `:powerdifference [BbNn] 3 3` guarantees that White has exactly one more minor piece than Black. The `:flipcolor` at the end does the same search with the roles reversed. By default, CQL inserts a "MATCH" comment in the games of the resulting output.pgn at the positions that warrant their inclusion, so you can quickly locate the exchange sacs.

Comment: awesome, sounds like kind of thing I was looking for CQL-wise. Do you use CQL implementation from http://www.rbnn.com/cql/ ?

Comment: @Joe, yes, that's the one I used.

Comment: Great answer, I didn't know such a thing existed.